# How to track all user activity on my website (like Chrome DevTools)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to know how I get all information of user activity who visit my website (with JavaScript), for example:

1. where user clicked on my website
2. all network calls on my website
3. all errors on his console

I want to access all information of Chrome's DevTool or browser just like dev tools do of client who visit my website.

JavaScript:

```
performance.memory.jsHeapSizeLimit
performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize
```

Any JSON of combined output may be `--` with user knowing it.

Comment: There are many tutorials on this topic. Here's an outline which you'll investigate yourself further 1) an event listener for `mousedown` or `click` events, 2) it depends on how you make those calls, usually trivial to implement but impossible to suggest anything without seeing your real code or knowing your framework/library, 3) add a listener for `error` on `window`. To send all that info to your server API you can use any library for this purpose or navigator.sendBeacon or ReportingObserver in new Chrome.

Comment: It was great help, thanks for the reply.